# In AngularJS 1.x, if we place a service object on scope and watch it, how is it different from watching a function that returns this service object?

Tags: angularjs

In https://jsfiddle.net/ejuru864/1/, we can watch a service object by:

```
    scope.myService = myService;

    scope.$watch("myService", function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("Wow I got triggered with", newVal, oldVal)
    }, true);
```

and if we remove the first line of code above, then the watch won't get triggered because it is not on the scope.  TO see it: https://jsfiddle.net/ejuru864/1/

Another way to watch it is to watch a function that returns the service object:

https://jsfiddle.net/ejuru864/2/

```
    scope.$watch(function() { return myService }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("Wow I got triggered with", newVal, oldVal)
    }, true);
```

If there is no need to display the service object on the view, is watching the function better than placing the service object on the scope and watch it? How does placing the service object on the scope affect memory and CPU usage if the service object can becomes quite big (say, when printed as Json, a few MB)?

Comment: Why would you put the service on the scope if the view doesn't need to access it? It doesn't cost anything (just the cost of a reference to an object), but it's useless. Watching an object that has a few MBs worth is extremely expensive, OTOH. Why are you doing that? What do you want to achieve? What sort of service needs a few MBs of memory?

Comment: if not watching the whole service object, then would you just set a dirty flag in the service object and watch the dirty flag?  Then you have to remember always set the dirty flag.  It could be, say a few MB, if the object points to other objects in the system.  But I suppose if each object is a few kb printed as Json, then 100 of them is a few hundred kb and not even one MB.  But how big is too big?

Comment: I don't know how I would do it, because you didn't say what you tried to achieve in the first place. You just assume that a watch is the only solution, but that is often not true. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: let's say if there is a page where various components and sub-components on the page can manipulate a shopping cart content.  I would have used 2-way binding for all cases to bind to this cart content object, but the existing code already used a factory to return an empty object to store the cart content and share it among all controllers and directives, so that's why the `$watch` is there to observe on the cart content object

Comment: @JBNizet comment added